# MAC, tkinter, imagecodecs: The kernel appears to have died. it will restart automatically

Tags: tkinter, button, jupyter-notebook, directory

I am on MAC (intel: its not M1 nor M2) and use jupyter notebook. I am trying to select a folder from the computer. When selecting a file with tkinter and imagecodecs, when clicking on the following button, the kernel stops.

[image]

I already did:

> brew install python-tk

I do not know how to deal with this problem.
Thank you for your help.